# Change Higcharts Tooltip value

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to change a value in the Highcharts tooltip?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
        {
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]}]

    });
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LBsL5/

Only the series 2 value should be in `timeformat` as `HH:MM` (216.4 = 3 Hours and 36 Minutes).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tooltip `pointFormatter` to calculate the hours and minutes and return the formatting you want. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBsL5/3/)):

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        var hours = ("0" + Math.floor(this.y / 60)).slice(-2);
        var minutes = ("0" + Math.round(this.y - (Math.floor(this.y / 60) * 60))).slice(-2);

        return '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> '
                +this.series.name+': <b>'+hours+':'+minutes+'</b><br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Anwser

but only the series 2 values shold bee in timeformat.
Is this possible too?

Greatings René

Comment: You can do a check for which series is being hovered. See http://jsfiddle.net/LBsL5/4/

Comment: Thanks alot this is it. You are great.